# Erlang how to supervise multi module

Tags: erlang, multiprocessing, erlang-supervisor

```
start_link() ->
supervisor:start_link(m_supervisor, []).

init(_Args) ->
{ok, {{one_for_one, 1, 60},
      [{m_clock, {m_clock, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_clock]},
        {m_sensor_f, {m_sensor_f, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_sensor_f]},
        {m_sensor_c, {m_sensor_c, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_sensor_c]},
        {m_converter, {m_converter, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_converter]},
        {m_supervisor, {m_supervisor, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_supervisor]},
        {m_display, {m_display, start_link, []},
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_display]}
        ]}}.
```

How can I supervise multi modules in one supervisor?

When I start to run this supervisor, it tells me:

```
** exception exit: {shutdown,
                   {failed_to_start_child,m_sensor_f,
                       {badarg,
                           [{erlang,register,[sensor,<0.51.0>],[]},
                            {m_sensor_f,start_sensor_f,2,
                                [{file,"m_sensor_f.erl"},{line,46}]},
                            {m_sensor_f,init,1,
                                [{file,"m_sensor_f.erl"},{line,16}]},
                            {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,306}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}}}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like more than one of the modules try to register the name `sensor`, i.e. they call something like `gen_server:start_link({local, sensor}, ?MODULE, {}, [])`. Either use unique names, or start the processes without names, e.g. `gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, {}, [])`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that you are trying to start the same supervisor again as the child of its own. So it will go into infinite loop and fails while registering the process with the same name second time.

```
> {m_supervisor, {m_supervisor, start_link, []},
>         permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [m_supervisor]},
```